# Replicating python string behavior in C

Tags: python, c, arrays, string, char

I'm trying to learn C, and I thought a good way to do so was to rework some programing praxis problems that I did in python. I'm currently working on [this](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/01/01/happy-new-year/) one.

My solution:

```
def main():
    nums = ["10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
    ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/", ""]

    recursive(nums, ops, "", 0)

def recursive(nums, ops, current_str, num_ind):
    if num_ind == len(nums)-1:
        # print current_str + nums[num_ind]
        if eval(current_str + nums[num_ind]) == 2013:
            print current_str + nums[num_ind]
        return 0
    else: 
        current_str = current_str + nums[num_ind]
        num_ind += 1
        for i in range(len(ops)):
            recursive(nums, ops, current_str+ops[i], num_ind)
```

Python performs some witchery when doing recursive function calls where it creates a new string per function call i.e. "" results in "10" which results in "10+", "10-", "10*", "10/", "10" so on and so forth for every permutation. An example if you uncommented that print statement:

```
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2-1
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2*1
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2/1
10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+21
```

Seeing how hands on you have to be with memory allocation and strings in C, is it even possible to do that sort of "forking" behavior that python exhibits in C?

**UPDATE:**

Figured it out,

```
int recursive(char** nums, char** ops, char* current_str, int num_ind){
    int i, ret;
    char new_str[100];

    num_ind++;
    if(num_ind == 9){
        //printf("%s\n", strcat(current_str,nums[num_ind]));
        ret = eval(strcat(current_str, nums[num_ind]));
        if(ret == 2013){
            printf("%s\n", current_str);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0; i<5; i++){
        strcpy(new_str, current_str);
        strcat(new_str, nums[num_ind]);
        recursive(nums, ops, strcat(new_str, ops[i]), num_ind);
    }
}
```

Comment: Python is implemented in C. So yes, it's possible :-) You'll need to allocate memory for each new string, and manually fill the allocated memory with the string contents.

Comment: `eval`, though, is going to be substantially tougher to implement without external libraries...

Comment: Nitpick ... CPython is implemented in C.

Comment: Side comment: it is a bad idea to use C like python (or python like C for that matter). You should try to learn the idioms of C, not replicate how things are done in python.

Comment: @nneonneo yes, yes it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. Use `malloc` and `free` to allocate memory for each invocation. Some very complex program that process text, like a compiler, are written in C. They are just hugely painful compare to Python. Or you can use C++, which has a string class so that you can do basic thing like string concatenation more easily.